# How to setup Github action to only run if a specified git tag does not exist

Tags: github-actions

I'm working to create a github action that will create a release draft. In the action I'd like to only run the release code if the app version does not have an respective git tag

The current action yaml looks similar to:

```
# ...

jobs:
  # test, winbuild and linuxbuild jobs


  draftrelease:
    needs: [test, winbuild, linuxbuild]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # if ${{jobs.test.steps.appversion.outputs.version}} is not a tag
    steps:
      # ...
```

I know I can use the following to print if the tag exists, but I need to check if the tag does not exist within the if:

```
git show-ref --tags --verify -- "refs/tags/${{jobs.test.steps.appversion.outputs.version}}"
```

How would I go about setting up the job to only run if `jobs.test.steps.appversion.outputs.versions` is not a git tag?

Comment: there is [this](https://camel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yamlref.html) still going *There is no official YAML reference guide. The YAML website only offers the YAML specification, which is a dense and thorny tome*. It feels like all CI related scripts out there are copy-pasted from each other and not many actually understanding what it does, therefore unable to modify it to fit their needs. I need this too and placed a bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by using a module that reads the app version, checking git tags, and then checking a variable at each step of the build:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    name: Compile Bundles
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest, ubuntu-latest]

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master branch
        uses: 'actions/checkout@v2'

      # Fetches all tags for the repo
      - name: Fetch tags
        run: git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*

      # Reads the app's version
      #   In my case, I have a nodejs project, so I read the app's version
      #   from package.json. You may need to find a different github action
      #   module specific to your language to extract the app version
      - name: Read package.json
        id: package
        uses: gregoranders/nodejs-project-info@v0.0.1

      # Check if the app version has a git tag
      # If there is a git tag for the version set the variable 'tagged' to 0
      # if there is NOT a git tag for the version set the variable 'tagged' to 1
      - name: 'Check: package version has corrosponding git tag'
        id: tagged
        shell: bash
        run: git show-ref --tags --verify --quiet -- "refs/tags/v${{ steps.package.outputs.version }}" && echo "::set-output name=tagged::0" || echo "::set-output name=tagged::1"

      - name: Step to only run if there is no git-tag for the version
        if: steps.tagged.outputs.tagged == 1
        # ...

      - name: Another step to only run if there is no git-tag for the version
        if: steps.tagged.outputs.tagged == 1
        # ...
```

The two big things to note is the `git --show-ref` line and then the `if:` statements that follow in later steps

```
# Attempt to output the tagged reference for the app's version
# In my case all version tags are prefixed with 'v' so you may need to alter
# this line to better suit your needs
git show-ref --tags --verify --quiet -- "refs/tags/v${{ steps.package.outputs.version }}"

  # If outputting the tag was successful set the variable indicating the tag exists
  && echo "::set-output name=tagged::0"

  # if outputting failed/errored, set the variable indicating the tag does not exist
  || echo "::set-output name=tagged::1
```

Once the above has been ran, then the github actions variable `steps.tagged.outputs.tagged` will be 0 if the version has been tagged, and 1 if the version has not been tagged.

From there you just need to check that variable with each step you only want to run if the version has not been tagged:

```yaml
if: steps.tagged.outputs.tagged == 1
```

[Git Show-ref Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref)

[Github Actions Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference)